# Processing file with xargs for concurrency

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

There is an input like:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
...
foldern
```

I would like to iterate over taking multiple lines at once and processes each line, remove the first / (and more but for now this is enough) and echo the. Iterating over in bash with a single thread can be slow sometimes. The alternative way of doing this would be splitting up the input file to N pieces and run the same script with different input and output N times, at the end you can merge the results.

I was wondering if this is possible with xargs.

Update 1:

Input:

```
/a/b/c
/d/f/e
/h/i/j
```

Output:

```
mkdir a/b/c
mkdir d/f/e
mkdir h/i/j
```

Script:

```
for i in $(<test); do 
  echo mkdir $(echo $i | sed 's/\///') ; 
done
```

Doing it with xargs does not work as I would expect:

```
xargs -a test -I line --max-procs=2 echo mkdir $(echo $line | sed 's/\///')
```

Obviously I need a way to execute the sed on the input for each line, but using $() does not work.

Comment: You'll need to illustrate better what you're trying to accomplish. Small sets of sample files/data followed by the expected output from that input will make it much easier to help. Good luck

Comment: *..."and echo the."* `echo` the what?

Comment: You should also look at [Gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) which helps run things in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
--max-procs=max-procs, -P max-procs
          Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is  1.   If
          max-procs  is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at
          a time.  Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances  are  that
          only one exec will be done.
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat file | perl -pe s:/:: | parallel mkdir -p
```

or:

```
cat file | parallel mkdir -p {= s:/:: =}
```